# To copy entire subfiles to other (only one) folder without path in windows platform

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, copy, xcopy

I did lots of search however i couldnt achieve what i want to do :

I have a folder which contains lots of folders and files under it. I just want to copy entire JPEG files in this folder to another folder without copying previous path tree.
I used this batch command like that :

for /r "C:\source" %%f in ("*.JPG") do @copy %%f "C:\dest" /Y

It works some files which dont contain any space in the name of files. However, it doesnt work files which contains space in file name like that :

it can find and copy  "aabb.JPEG" 
it can not copy "aa bb.JPEG"

any solutions?

Comment: Try adding quotes around %%f

Comment: works : for /r "C:\source\" %%f in ("*.JPG") do @copy "%%f" "C:\dest\" /Y

Comment: doesnt work : for /r "C:\source\" "%%f" in ("*.JPG") do @copy "%%f" "C:\dest\" /Y

Answer (score 0):

The following works great for me

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /R "c:\source" %%F IN (*.jpg) DO (
  copy "%%F" "c:\dest\" /Y
)
```